# How to parse a CSV file which has items multiple lines long, and content that changes, and add those items to a sharedpreference file

Tags: android, string, parsing, csv, sharedpreferences

In my android app, when the user refreshes one of the listviews in my app a .csv file is downloaded. That .csv file is generated on the server, and changes every day, as the number of groups of items in it varies day to day. Now a number of those items are very big (multiple lines long) and have a number of formatting elements in them. Now I would like to take these items, which are separated using "quote comma quote" and be able to parse all these items, no matter how many of them they are, and put them in a shared preferences file where they are sorted by some category (ex. "date" "title" "description" "data"). I have experimented with a number of ways to do this, but always only get the last group of items in my csv file (a group of items is an entry, the number of groups of items is what varies when a user refreshes, since the number of groups usually varies). Addtionally a number of the longer items in my csv file are cut off, with only the first line of it showing. So how can I accommodate for the varying number of groups in my csv file, and manage to get all the items in the groups to a shared preference file where they are sorted by what type of item they are.

Eventually these items will be put in a list view.

Here is an example csv file, similar to what I will be dealing with: http://www.beaconschool.org/~markovic/lincoln.php

Here is what I have tried to do before, which has resulted in just the last group of items being saved to the shared preference file, and the larger items (larger number of lines) being cut off.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.beaconschool.org/~markovic/lincoln.php");
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
    String result = "";



    try {
        Log.d("receiver", "animation stopped and downloaded file");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(
          response.getEntity().getContent()

                )


                );



        CSVReader csvreader = new CSVReader(reader);


        String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {



                String[] RowData = line.split("\",\"");


                System.out.println(RowData.length);

                if (RowData.length > 0) {
                Data = RowData[0];
                }

                if (RowData.length > 1) {
                Band = RowData[1];
                }


                if (RowData.length > 2) {
                Number = RowData[2];

                }

                if (RowData.length > 3) {
                Class = RowData[3];
                }

                if (RowData.length > 4) {
                Teacher = RowData[4];
                }

                if (RowData.length > 5) {
                Title = RowData[5];
                }

                if (RowData.length > 6) {
                Date = RowData[6];
                }

                if (RowData.length > 7) {
                Type = RowData[7];
                }

                if (RowData.length > 8) {
                Description = RowData[8];
                }



                 SharedPreferences.Editor localEditor = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("due_today", Context.MODE_PRIVATE ).edit();

                 localEditor.putString("data", Data.toString());
                 localEditor.putString("band", Band.toString());
                 localEditor.putString("number", Number.toString());
                 localEditor.putString("class", Class.toString());
                 localEditor.putString("teacher", Teacher.toString());
                 localEditor.putString("title", Title.toString());
                 localEditor.putString("date", Date.toString());
                 localEditor.putString("type", Type.toString());
                 localEditor.putString("description", Description.toString());
```

Comment: You are throwing away all. Twice. First you specify only 9 items (0-8) where there are much more. All items are on one line except for the last one where the 'subitems' occucupy a line each. Second you are using readLine() and split on "," which makes no sense on all the lines which only contain one subitem.

Comment: So how would I declare which items are on which rows and how do you suggest I deal with the item that has multiple sub items? Also when am I throwing away what I have parsed and how to avoid that?

Comment: This is a very peculiar csv file. I see no 'records'. Or do i see 2? Normally every 'record' is on a line and the values/items separated by a comma. And then some items/values can be quoted. So you are in no luck with this file. You could try the following: read the file completely in one string. Then split on ",". Loop through all items of the split and try to split again on \n. If you can split on \n then you have your 'subitems'.

Comment: This is what happens when the Android app guy and the server side guy never communicate. But yes I agree this seems to be the way to go, to turn all the text in the file into a string and just split that to some prevail. Thank you for your help.